# Can I create an OpenShift template from multiple files?

Tags: openshift

I am wondering if it is possible to create a single openshift template from multiple individual files (nicely grouped inside some folder).

Kind of like how you'd approach separating the different microservices you're deploying in kubernetes in separate `yml` files and then `kubectl apply -f <folder_name>`.

From a quick look at the docs, it doesn't look like it's possible, but I might be missing something...?

It seems odd to force people who need a template to use a single file that can easily grow to a few thousands lines of code (e.g. if your template is for a multi-component application) and coming from the `terraform` Developer Experience, it even seems counter-intuitive now...

Comment: For more complex templating look at Helm. Just be aware that Helm doesn't play nice with OpenShift because OpenShift enforces a quite strict security regime. It is hoped the next major version of Helm will be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the yaml files sequentially. Assuming your template consists of 2 files template_part1.yaml and template_part2.yaml:

```
oc process -f /myfiles/template_part1.yaml | oc create -f -
oc process -f /myfiles/template_part2.yaml | oc create -f -
```